# How do you modify the query parameters on an OAuth authentication request URL when using Microsoft Katana?

Tags: oauth, asp.net-mvc-5, owin, katana

I have ASP.Net MVC 5 using the Identity Framework and OWIN to allow users to sign in via OAuth.

Specifically I'm currently working on authenticating against Twitter, and I'd like to add `force_login=true` so that users are able to choose which account to use, rather than being automatically authenticated with the account they're already signed in to twitter with.

I've tracked down this code which appears to construct the URL and as far as I can see offers no points at which I can modify the URL.

[Microsoft.Owin.Security.Twitter/TwitterAuthenticationHandler.cs](https://katanaproject.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/Microsoft.Owin.Security.Twitter/TwitterAuthenticationHandler.cs)

The class is internal in an Microsoft assembly so the only option I can see available is to copy that class and all required supporting code, then manually keep it in sync with the original if they make changes.

Is there another approach that I'm missing?

I would really rather avoid creating a maintenance nightmare if it can be avoided.

Comment: In ApplyResponseChallengeAsync have you tried hooking into `Options.Provider.ApplyRedirect(redirectContext)`?

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear in my question. I'm not looking for how to modify that code, I'm looking for how to not have to create my own version of that code and then keep it in sync with any changes that Microsoft make in the future.

Comment: Oh, apologies, I see what you mean! I shall check it out now.

Comment: I've hooked in to OnApplyRedirect in the provider options, and while it's not perfect it's waaay better than what I'd come up with. Would you mind leaving that comment as an answer so I can accept it and give you the recognition you deserve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can hook into Options.Provider.ApplyRedirect(redirectContext) and it will be called from ApplyResponseChallengeAsync.

Comment: The 'TwitterAuthenticationOptions.Provider' property has a property called 'OnApplyRedirect' which takes a delegate that will perform the redirect. I replaced it with a redirect which modifies the URL.
OnApplyRedirect = async (context) =>
                    {
                        context.Response.Redirect(context.RedirectUri + "&force_login=true");
                    }